# Get value from child process

Tags: c

Is it possible to get value (always integer) from child process (which further uses exec() system call) **without** using pipe, writing to a file or shared memory process. We can only use following system calls

**fork, exec* family, ato* family, printf, sprintf, malloc, free, wait/ waitpid, sqrt, exit**

I have thought of using WEXITSTATUS but it will return only number upto 255.

1. main program reads user input number
2. Calls fork()
3. child process uses exec() to load some another executable with numer as command line argument
4. this executale perform something on the number and changes its value (suppose it multiplies number with 81)
5. parent process waits for child to exit or return
6. Now parent process should print value modified in child process

What i have done is that I am using WEXITSTATUS to catch the return value of child process. But this will work only if number is less than 255

Original Problem:
you need to write three c programs defined in square.c, double.c and
root.c which perform square, double and square
root operations respectively on a non-negative integer such that generated exe-
cutables with these programs can be chained in any pattern.
The order of the operations in the chained pattern would be from left to right.

./square root double root 8

You must only use the below mentioned APIs to implement this question fork exec* family strcpy strcmp ato* family printf, sprintf round strtok wait/ waitpid sqrt exit

[IMG1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ysvZ3.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UmuPv.png)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236557/discussion-on-question-by-jack-king-get-value-from-child-process).